# MVC routing to subdomains

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, subdomain, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a website with the following sub domains pointing to their own different folders on the server.

- mydomain.com
- content.mydomain.com
- api.mydomain.com
- forum.mydomain.com
- blog.mydomain.com

Wildcard SSL certificates is extrmely expensive, compared to normal SSL certificates. so securing the subdomains have to be achieved some other way.

Is there any way i can secure the subdomains, via routing, ex: add a route on the website mydomain.com/api, and let that then point to the subdomain?

mydomain.com/api will then be secured using a normal ssl certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Use htacess file for url rewriting. This way subdomains will be there but main url is of your site which is already having SSL installed. For e.g.

```
https : / / content.mydomain.com => https : / / mydomain.com/content
```

Comment: lemme play around with this, will give feedback later

Answer (score 0):

> Wildcard SSL certificates is extrmely expensive, compared to normal SSL certificates. so securing the subdomains have to be achieved some other way.

Security must be done at multiple levels in order to work. At the application level, you can provide an authentication mechanism. However, it is completely worthless without SSL because the password that the user logs in with will be sent across the wire in plain text.

SSL encrypts the connection between the user's browser and your server. There is NO replacement for this. Your best option to secure multiple domains is to get a wildcard certificate (or a cheaper provider).